# LINQ Loop getting slower after some times

Tags: linq, optimization

I am running a code, to extract hyperlinks using regular expression from 1 million documents, at the beginning, the code run very quickly initially (about 200 docs per second) but later on it becomes very slow, as slow as 10 docs per second, does anyone experience this before? The code is below.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExtractHyperLinks();

        }

        private static void ExtractHyperLinks()
        {
            DataContext dc = new DataContext();

            var docs = from p in dc.docs
                       select p;

            Regex reUrl = new Regex(@"((https?):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)");

            int counter = 0;

            foreach (Document d in docs)
            {                
                Match m = reUrl.Match(tweet.Text);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    Hyperlink h = new Hyperlink();
                    h.Url = m.Value;
                    dc.Hyperlinks.InsertOnSubmit(h);
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                    Console.WriteLine(h.Url);
                }
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `new Regex(..., RegexOptions.Compiled)`.

Comment: Console.WriteLine is not a very speedy call

Comment: You might also try moving SubmitChanges outside the loop, might give you some performance improvements.

Comment: +1 to that - I'd time the parsing out hyperlinks into new Hyperlinks objects separate from then adding them (InsertAllOnSubmit, SubmitChanges).  Also, the regex appears to do a bunch of capture groups you're not using?

Comment: btw, if you're trying to obscure the documents as being tweets, you missed one spot. :)

Comment: maybe move the regex into a private static readonly and make the foreach into a linq expression to generate the Hyperlinks?  Then you could docs.AsParallel() at the start to at least get some multi-core help :)

Comment: my guess about the current perf issue, FWIW, is that the context holds on to all the submitted hyperlinks, so your memory use goes up and the perf drops as you hit memory pressure and the GC has to try harder (although you could check memory usage over time easily enough)

Comment: @JamesManning not really trying to mask it, just try to generalise it as I got critisized by someone before

Comment: If I move the submitchanges outside the loop, it will end up a big update in the end won't it ? What I did is to move the dc inside and reinstate a new dc everytime and the problem is gone, but that seems to be a silly method.

Comment: FWIW, with that many rows I would SqlBulkCopy. We use it at my work and it works very well.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the foreach loop to a for i =0 to numOfDocs, then get by docs[i].  Also, what's the counter for?